ASP.NET Core 8 MVC and Identity - empty fields
I have a problem with my identity in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, because when I try to fill in the data, regardless of whether it is login or registration, my validation pops up, which I did, stating that email and password are required. However, I enter these data and it looks as if identity did not see the data entered in the form and after clicking log in/register it showed an empty fields error.
Just like this:
Email: admin@example.com
Password: Admin123!

Then when I click Log in I have my validation message like email and password is required...
Here is my code:
Register.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Wypożyczalnia_samochodów_online.Services;

namespace Wypożyczalnia_samochodów_online.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly EmailService _emailService;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public RegisterModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, EmailService emailService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailService = emailService;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email jest wymagany.")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Nieprawidłowy format adresu email.")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Hasło jest wymagane.")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Hasło musi mieć co najmniej {2} i maksymalnie {1} znaków.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Potwierdzenie hasła jest wymagane.")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Hasła muszą się zgadzać.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = Input.Email,
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    EmailConfirmed = false // Domyślnie niepotwierdzony
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    // Generowanie tokena potwierdzenia e-mail
                    var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                    // Tworzenie linku do potwierdzenia
                    var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, token }, Request.Scheme);

                    // Wysyłanie wiadomości e-mail z potwierdzeniem
                    await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(
                        Input.Email,
                        "Potwierdzenie rejestracji",
                        $"Kliknij w poniższy link, aby potwierdzić rejestrację: <a href='{confirmationLink}'>Potwierdź</a>"
                    );

                    // Logowanie użytkownika (opcjonalne) lub przekierowanie
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                // Obsługa błędów rejestracji
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}

Register.cshtml:
@page
@model Wypożyczalnia_samochodów_online.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Rejestracja";
}


<div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="text-center">Zarejestruj się</h2>
                <hr />
                <form method="post">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Wpisz swój e-mail" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wpisz swoje hasło" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Potwierdź swoje hasło" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Zarejestruj</button>
                </form>


                <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                    <a asp-page="./Login">Masz już konto? Zaloguj się</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
            {
                <li>@error.ErrorMessage</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}

And login.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Wypożyczalnia_samochodów_online.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email jest wymagany.")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Nieprawidłowy format adresu email.")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Hasło jest wymagane.")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Jeśli dane wejściowe są nieprawidłowe
                return Page();
            }

            // Znajdź użytkownika po e-mailu
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Nie znaleziono użytkownika.");
                return Page();
            }

            // Spróbuj zalogować użytkownika
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Jeśli użytkownik to admin, przekieruj na stronę admina
                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Reports", "Admin");
                }

                // Przekierowanie do strony docelowej
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Twoje konto jest zablokowane.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Nieprawidłowe dane logowania.");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}

login.cshtml:
@page
@model Wypożyczalnia_samochodów_online.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Logowanie";
}

<div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="text-center">Zaloguj się</h2>
                <hr />

                @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
                            {
                                <li>@error.ErrorMessage</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                }

                <form method="post">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Wpisz swój e-mail" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wpisz swoje hasło" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Zaloguj się</button>
                </form>

                <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                    <a asp-page="./Register">Nie masz konta? Zarejestruj się</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your code looks good; try giving your form an id and decorate your OnPostAsync methods with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

okey I fixed the problem, I didnt have a _ViewImports.cshtml in the right place (Identity->Pages)
